# How to map properties of an object to another?

Tags: javascript, schema, lodash, normalizr

I know there are many questions on this matter, but I can't figure out how to apply it in my case.

Code is as following:

```
const mailDocumentSchema = new schema.Entity('mailDocuments', {}, { idAttribute: 'identifier' });
const mailSchema = new schema.Entity('mails', { emailDocument: [mailDocumentSchema] }, { idAttribute: 'identifier' });
const mailAccountSchema = new schema.Entity('mailAccounts', { mails: [mailSchema] }, { idAttribute: 'address' });

const mailMapper = (item: any): Mail => ({
  id: item.identifier,
  title: item.subject,
  documents: item.emailDocument,
  subject: item.realSubject,
  receiver: item.receiver,
  createdDate: item.createdDate,
  sendDate: item.sendDate,
  body: item.body
});

const mailDocumentMapper = (item: any): MailDocument => ({
  id: item.identifier,
  docId: item.oldDocId,
  name: item.name,
  createdDate: item.createdDate,
  bodyStatus: item.bodyStatus
});

export const undefinedDocumentsMapper = (response: any[]): NormalizedMailbox => {
  const undefinedDocuments = map(groupBy(response, item => item.receiver), (item, key) => ({ name: null, address: key, mails: item }));
  const normalizedResponse = normalize(undefinedDocuments, [mailAccountSchema]);
  return {
    mailAccounts: Object.values<MailAccount>(normalizedResponse.entities.mailAccounts),
    mails: Object.values<any>(normalizedResponse.entities.mails).map(mailMapper),
    mailDocuments: Object.values<any>(normalizedResponse.entities.mailDocuments).map(mailDocumentMapper) 
  };
};
```

API response is:

```
[
   { identifier: "...", title: "...", receiver: "...", emailDocuments: [{...}] },
   ...
]
```

What I want is to map the `receiver` and `title` properties from `mails` entity objects to `mailDocuments` entity objects.

As a result to get `mailDocuments` entity objects as such:

```
{
  id: "...",
  docId: "...",
  name: "...",
  createdDate: "...",
  bodyStatus: ...,
  title: "...",
  receiver: "..."
}
```

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do the following:

```
mails.forEach(mail => {
  mail.documents.forEach(document => {
    document.receiver = email.receiver
    document.title = email.title
  })
})
```